# Bordering Zipcodes

Tags: python, geospatial

How would I find bording zipcodes or zipcodes in a nearby radius to known zip codes that were affected by a hurricane (in python)? I have a list of over 1000 zip codes affected by Hurricane Irma in Florida.

I want to delete all duplicates, and not include zipcodes that were affected by the hurricane.

There are files on census.gov that list latitude and longitude of every zipcode.

Comment: Great! What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "bordering zipcodes"? If you want to figure out the proximity of one zip code to another, you can find the latitudinal/longitudinal coordinates of each zip code via census.gov and use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).